# Django object on creation isn't stored in the database and the ID is returned as null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a basic notes application where user can perform CRUD operation.

Following are my models, views and URLs.

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


class Notes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.created_on = timezone.now()
    self.last_updated = timezone.now()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import serializers, models


class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Notes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.NotesSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def list(self, request):
    notes = models.Notes.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    serializer = serializers.NotesSerializer(notes, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def create(self, request):
    serializer = serializers.NotesSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    note = models.Notes.objects.filter(id=pk)
    serializer = serializers.NotesSerializer(instance=note)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    note = models.Notes.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = serializers.NotesSerializer(
        instance=note, data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)

def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    note = models.Notes.objects.get(id=pk)
    note.delete()
    return Response({"message": "Note deleted"},
                    status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import NotesViewSet

app_name = 'notes'

urlpatterns = [
    path('get', NotesViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'list',
    }), name='get'),
    path('create', NotesViewSet.as_view({
        'post': 'create',
    }), name='create'),
    path('get/<str:pk>', NotesViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'retrieve',
    }), name='retrieve'),
    path('update/<str:pk>', NotesViewSet.as_view({
        'put': 'update',
    }), name='update'),
    path('delete/<str:pk>', NotesViewSet.as_view({
        'delete': 'destroy',
    }), name='delete'),
]
```

My question is, once I send a post request to create a new note something like this coming back as a response

```
{
    "id": null,
    "title": "title_1",
    "body": "body_1",
    "created_on": "2021-06-02T21:10:42.019236+05:30",
    "last_updated": "2021-06-02T21:10:42.019257+05:30",
    "user": 1
}
```

and the data isn't stored in the database as well. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in how you've overridden your save method- you still need to call the parent's save on it to get your expected behavior.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.created_on = timezone.now()
    self.last_updated = timezone.now()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Your code has some odd tabulation under your `Notes` class- I'm assuming this is just an issue in the code within the question.

Comment: @paul_ebin glad it worked. However- your current save() method is redundant. Your fields have `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` which achieve the behavior your save() method is doing. In many cases you're better off not using custom model save() methods if you can avoid it.

Comment: Hey @rob,  I removed the overridden save() method and everything is working as expected. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
super()
```

in save method is missing. You need to call super().save(*args, **kwargs) to make it work.